# When the global section functor is a Cartesian fibration?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, topos-theory, infinity-categories, infinity-topos-theory

Given a Cartesian fibration $p : \mathbf{E} \to \mathbf{B}$ over an $\infty$-topos the paper by Marc Hoyois mentioned in his answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294014/generalizations-of-tangent-infty-topos) gives some sufficient conditions for $\mathbf{E}$ to be an $\infty$-topos. I'd like to know when the converse holds. That is, if we have a functor between toposes $p : \mathbf{E} \to \mathbf{B}$, when it is a Cartesian fibration? Since this question is probably too general, it may be assumed that $p$ is the direct image of a geometric morphism and even more that it is the global section functor $\mathrm{Hom}(1,-) : \mathbf{E} \to \mathrm{\infty Grpd}$.

More generally, if $\mathbf{C}$ is an arbitrary $\infty$-category with a terminal object, when the functor $\mathrm{Hom}(1,-) : \mathbf{C} \to \mathrm{\infty Grpd}$ is a Cartesian fibration? Since this question is also probably too general, it may be assumed, if it helps, that $\mathbf{C}$ is locally presentable and that $\mathrm{Hom}(1,-)$ has a right adjoint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact I believe something quite general can be said: if $p:C\to D$ is any functor that preserves finite limits, then it is a [Street fibration](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Street+fibration) if and only if it has a fully faithful right adjoint.  A Street fibration is just a functor whose isofibrant replacement is a cartesian fibration in the usual sense; this is the only sensible thing to ask about a functor between given toposes, since toposes are really only well-defined up to equivalence of categories.  A sketch of the proof of this is [here](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/11/discreteness_concreteness_fibr.html), and I think it should generalize straightforwardly to $(\infty,1)$-categories.

If $p$ is the direct image functor of a geometric morphism, then it has a fully faithful right adjoint if and only if that geometric morphism is [local](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/local+geometric+morphism), a familiar topos-theoretic property.